# Transact-SQL & Different SQL Dialects

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, pdf

I'm looking for a complete/definitive guild/specification for T-SQL, and to a lesser extent all of the different SQL dialects.

I have decent material(PDFs) on MS SQL server, and it covers T-SQL.  But I would really like to find something more like a language spec.

Like wise, I would love to find a DEFINITIVE and COMPLETE PDF comparing all of the different SQL dialects.

I sometimes use this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference

It's ok, but not complete.  And it doesn't come as a whole/complete doc/PDF, but rather a collection of pages.

Not as important, but I would also like to find a PDF devoted to MySQL, specifically Workbench.

For my use, it's important that they are PDFs or could be covered without much effort because I read them & comment them of Acrobat/Reader.  I find being able to take notes on the doc goes a long way with me.

Interested to see what you've found.  Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this exits the frustrating part is that all of the engines use there own branch of T-SQL and its really the minutia that trips you up

Comment: I was afraid this might be the case.  Thanks for your input all the same.

Comment: Do you think there is much difference between T-SQL for MS Server 2012 & 2014?  I was about to find this(Transact-SQL Data Definition Language - DDL- Reference 2012)(top hit): https://www.google.com/#q=transact+sql+language+reference+pdf

Comment: The only differences would be SQL related to new features in the engine https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510411.aspx  and features and syntax that has been deprecated https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx.

Comment: I would say those books online are going to be 90% similar in regards to basic syntax

Comment: This is worth a look.  http://it-ebooks.info/book/3725/